# Background images get preloaded but load again

Tags: jquery, css

I'm preloading a background image which I know is getting cached, but my code doesn't read it from the cache.  It loads it again as if it weren't cached.  The "imgSrcArray" actually contains 8 images, but I've hard coded this example for simplicity.

Anyone have any ideas?

```
imgSrcArray = ["images/img0"]; 

//preload image
$.each(imgSrcArray, function (i, val) {
    $(function() { 
        $(document.body).append($("<img id='imgHid" + i + "'/>").attr("src", val).hide()) 
    }); 
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bkgrnddiv').css('backgroundImage', 'url(images/img0)');   
});
```

Comment: I should have added that this is for a floated layout within a fixed width, so there is no explicit positioning.

Comment: Did you try to set absolute paths? Are the source attribute from the img-tags and the paths in #bkrnddiv the same?

Comment: $('#bkgrnddiv').css('backgroundImage') gives the fully qualified path for the image.

Comment: I just noticed that my code works in FF. I don't know why it didn't seem to be working earlier. So I think it's probably a display problem in IE, rather than a preloading problem. I'll update when I get it working in IE.

Comment: I created the problem by preloading the background images for all 8 pages in the site each time one of the pages was launched.  Now I'm only preloading one image per page and it's working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I've cleaned up your code a little bit and it loads the image only once. Maybe it had something to do with appending to the document load in the loop.

http://jsfiddle.net/Fuejf/

```js
var imgSrcArray = ['http://placekitten.com/200/300'];

function preload() {
    $.each(imgSrcArray, function(i, val) {
            $('body').append($("<img id='imgHid" + i + "'/>").attr("src", val).hide())

    });
}

$(function() {
    console.log('document loaded');
    preload();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('document ready');
    $('#bkgrnddiv').css({
        'background': 'transparent url(' + imgSrcArray +') no-repeat 0 50%'
    });
});​
```